# UICollectionView zoom entire grid

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I am using a UICollectionView to display a grid of cells with 3 columns. When a cell is selected, I'd like to zoom into the entire collection with the selected cell in the centre. I'd also like to fade out the surrounding cells and keep the selected on at full opacity.

The following code scales the grid but doesn't scroll to the selected cell:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: {
    self.collectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
})
```

I was hoping I could do it by changing the UICollectionViewFlowLayout and the UICollectionView frame but I'm not sure whether I'm going down the wrong path with this (the following code just moves all the cells over to the left):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, animations: {() -> Void in
    self.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(self.zoomedGridLayout, animated: true)
            
    let zoomedRect = CGRect(x: -rect.width, y: 0, width: rect.width*3, height: rect.height)
    self.collectionView.frame = zoomedRect
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
})
```

The collection view doesn't need to be scrollable after the animation (I intend to use it only as a transition to another view).